# append object to innerHTML and get that object from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, object, jsonp, innerhtml

[here is an example in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TUaT4/)

I want to know if I can append a javascript object to innerHTML, that get that object again from innerHTML as object.

something like,

```
alert((this.innerHTML).html);
```

that's just an example, don't ask me why do you need this?
I'm trying to edit an existing code, and I have to do this so.
I have to transfer an object via div.innerHTML.

Comment: I think the best way to go about this would be to use jQuery and store the object as a json string inside the div. On retrieval, use something like jQuery.parseJSON( <div contents> ) to fetch and convert to JS Object

Comment: thanks, but I can't use jQuery.

Comment: En- and decode it as JSON. You don't need jQuery for that, but not all browsers support the `JSON` object.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried that http://jsfiddle.net/sQ4vR/1/ but I'm getting unexpected error while parsing it, do you have any solution? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDLWf/). In it, I add the object to the div as a 'data-'-attribute, using JSON to convert it to a string. After that, adding some comment to the div triggers the `DOMSubtreeModified`-handler, in which the 'html'-part of the object is retrieved and alerted. It that something to work with?

Comment: Cool, but I think you may have obfuscated the goodness with the flashness. ;-p

Answer (score 1):

In this case, quite possible your only option is to convert your object to string and then put that into the element. (This is done by looping through the key, values building the string as you go.)

You would reverse the process to convert it back into an obj.

I know some javascript libary's have helper functions to make this process very simple.

You could try adding the data directly onto the dom element, rather than as its content..

```
tempDiv.objData = myObject;
```

Comment: Actually I understand know, that's a good way, I didn't know that I can do element.objData or something like that, but if I use that "DOMSubtreeModified" event will not fire. what about browser supports on element.<blabla> ?

Comment: Its not the most ideal way to store data, and the obj data is assigned to the variable itself not the actual element. I cannot find to much info regarding browser compatibility of this, but its working on my end. You cannot store the data anywhere else besides a specific element?

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested to use JSON, but no code. So:

```
function addObjAsJSON(el, obj) {
  el.setAttribute('data-myJSON', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)));
}

function getObjAsJSON(el) {
  return JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(el.getAttribute('data-myJSON')));
}
```

That should allow you to add anything as a serialised object, then get it back. You should add some error checking to make it robust though (e.g. check that you get a string back from the call to *getAttribute*).

For user agents that don't have built-in JSON support, see [json.org](http://json.org/) which has a link in the javascript section to [json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).